# How to add internationalization in a formtastic page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, formtastic

I tried to use default internationalization of formtastic and failed. I tried it as given in

https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/6.2-Customize:-Internationalization

So now i want to introduce internationalization using i18ln gem of rails in formtastic.

How can i do it?

This is the proposed form page

```
<%= semantic_form_for @detail do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>

    <%= f.input :name %>

    <%= f.input :dob  %> 
    <%= f.input :gender, :as => :radio, :label => "Gender", :collection => [["Male", 'male'], ["Female", 'female']] %>  
  <% end %>
  <%= f.actions do %>
    <%= f.action :submit, :as => :input %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is wk.yml file

```
en: 
formtastic:
  dob: Date of Birth
  name: Your Name
  Gender: gender
```

How to integrate both together?

Comment: Show up your `[i18n].yml` file, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, have you added `Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.i18n_lookups_by_default = true` in `formtastic.rb` initializer?

Try with:

```
wk: 
  formtastic:
    labels:
      detail:
        dob: "Date of Birth"
        name: "Your Name"
        gender: "gender"
```

Comment: I have added Formtastic::SemanticFormBuilder.i18n_lookups_by_default = true in formtastic.rb initializer.

Thanks for the rest let me try it.

Comment: Thank you it worked..

Can you explain me how i can call another [i18ln].yml file into the same page. For eg: wk.yml

Comment: It's a bit long... I suggest you to take a look at [Rails Internationalization API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and/or open a new question :)

Comment: i need to switch from 'en' to 'wk' and viseversa

Comment: Yes, I get it! Take a look at this great railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/138-i18n